# UPDATE all rows in SQL Server table in a Python script

Tags: python, sql-server

I am running a Python script where I call a SQL Server table and retrieve a directory from a column. The script goes to the file and scrapes several important elements to me. I have it working when I hard code a single directory and filename but I'm having trouble with this script to do it for all the appropriate filenames. When I run the select star to get the path and directory, it comes in a list here with double slashes and comes into what looks like JSON. I just need the directory and path and then I can execute the rest of my Python code. Any help is appreciated.

```
import html2text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=;'
                      'Database=00010KData;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cur = cnxn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT FullPath FROM EdgarComments')
results = cur.fetchall()

results
```

```
('F:\\FinancialResearch\\SEC\\myEdgar\\sec-edgar-filings\\A\\10-K\\0000894189-21-001890\\full-submission.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ', ),
 ('F:\\FinancialResearch\\SEC\\myEdgar\\sec-edgar-filings\\A\\10-K\\0000894189-21-001895\\filing-details.html                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ', ),
 ('F:\\FinancialResearch\\SEC\\myEdgar\\sec-edgar-filings\\A\\10-K\\0000894189-21-001895\\full-submission.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ', ),
 ('F:\\FinancialResearch\\SEC\\myEdgar\\sec-edgar-filings\\A\\10-K\\0000929351-21-000019\\filing-details.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the CONTENTS of the results with the REPRESENTATION of the results.  It is not JSON, that's just the way Python displays a tuple of strings.  `fetchall` returns a list of lists (or tuple of tuples), where each row contains one entry for each field.  Further, those double slashes are not actually present in the string.  Python just prints it that way so you can see other escape codes.

Just do:

```
for row in results:
    print(row[0])
```

and you'll have the information you need.